# Grouped SlickGrid with non-default rowHeight

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, slickgrid

I am using the [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) control as shown in the [grouped example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping)  If I set the rowHeight option to 200 then the grid also makes the slick-group row larger as well.

Is there anyway around this?  I have tried to manually adjust the CSS on that grouped row however then the grid doesn't adjust the row positioning of all the other rows.

Answer (score 2):

SlickGrid requires all rows to be the same height.

Comment: That is a severe limitation for using the grouping feature then.  I guess SlickGrid needs a groupedRowHeight property to the options.

Comment: It's a limitation of SlickGrid in general, though there are some forks on GitHub that implemented that.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any of the links for the forks on GitHub?